# What is a "for to by" loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix-multiplication, pseudocode

I am trying to do this matrix multiplication assignment for my parallel programming class, but I don't understand what my professor means with this "for to by" loop he has in the pseudocode. More specifically, why is the "by" there and how do I translate it into code? I am using C.

Here is the loop that he wants me to code as a part of this assignment:
variables A, B, and C are 2D arrays that I defined. n is the size of the two n by n matrices being multiplied together, and I do not know what the variable s is supposed to be after the "by" statement.

```
//Loop 3
for it = 1 to n by s do
for kt = 1 to n by s do
for jt = 1 to n by s do
 for i = it to min(it+s-1, n) do
  for k = kt to min(kt+s-1, n) do
   for j = jt to min(jt+s-1, n) do
    C[i,j] = C[i,j] + A[i,k] x B[k,j]
   endfor
  endfor
 endfor
endfor
endfor
endfor
```

Comment: `by s` probably means that the loop variable increases by `s` each iteration.

Comment: from `1` to `n` do something and keep incrementng by `s` steps in each iteration until it exceeds n.

Comment: Looks like VB, which either uses 1-indexed or 0-indexed arrays, depending on daily mood and the location of various astral bodies. C is always 0-indexed, so you should always start at 0.

Comment: Sounds like your prof is a Fortran fan (as am I). In a Fortran loop (`do label var = expr1, expr2, expr3`) 'expr3' is the step value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`by` is the amount to increment the iteration variable each time. In C you would use `it += s`. This is called the *step* or *stride*.

```
for (int it = 1; it <= n; it += s) { // for it = 1 to n by s do
    // body of loop
}
```

If you leave out `by s` it's assumed to be incrementing by `1`, and you would use `it++`.

Note that in C array indexes start at `0`, not `1`. So the loop would actually be

```
for (int it = 0; it < n; it += s)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @ConnorWilliams you should mark this answer as accepted